# Enlazar [(ngModel)] a model de dos niveles

Tags: angular, model

Quisiera Saber como puedo utilizar el [(ngModel)] para enlazarlo a model lo que hago es que ocupo el para capturar los datos y luego uno empleados pero nose como utilizar el ngmodel con dos niveles me da error al hacer esto

Esto me da error en la compilación...

Acá lo que esta en el Componentes.ts:

Empleados:{
  Nombre:'Noé',
  Transporte: {
    carro:true,
    moto: false
  };
};

Model:any={};

Comment: Añade el codigo completo y el mensaje de error si no es imposible ayudarte.

Comment: Trata de redactar tu pregunta de forma más clara porque mencionas un error pero no lo publicas. Es una pregunta poco clara